# Is there a way to force Powershell to open a document as read-only and close without saving?

Tags: powershell, file-io

I have a script that parses data from Word documents. I arrived to the office this morning to realize that the script hadn't completed, hanging on a "File In Use" dialog box. I found a reference to the `$true` parameter -- open Read-Only -- on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28v=office.11%29.ASPX), but I still get the dialog box.

[image]

And of course, one thing leading to another, *now* I also get the dialog box asking if I want to save changes before I can open the NEXT document, which can't be accessed because of an open dialog box. Sigh. How can I open a document, scan it for my data (the hyperlinks) and then close the document without saving?

[image]

Code appears here. I have not included the step where I write `$hyperlinks` to a file; I'm just concentrating on getting the file-read-close part working.

```
$global:word = new-object -ComObject Word.Application 
$word.Visible = $False 
$backupPath   = "\\Path\to\files\"   # Backup data path
$srcfiles     = Get-ChildItem $backupPath -filter "*.doc"
 #   
foreach ($doc in $srcfiles) {
    $word.documents.Open($doc.Fullname,$true);
    $links = @($doc2.Hyperlinks);
    $links
    $word.Quit();
}
```

Comment: I don't mess with COM much, but if the Microsoft Word Viewer is a COM application, it seems like that migh be a better choice for what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For read only, try this:

```
$word.Documents.Open("$doc.Fullname", $false, $true)
```

For closing, try this:

```
$word.Documents.Close($false)
```

The MSDN links seem pretty clear about the order these parameters need to appear in and the above worked for me.

Comment: For closing I had to use this: `$document.Close([ref] [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges)`. See [msdn Documents.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.close.aspx).

Comment: @webwurst you're right, but I found this works too by trial and error : `$document.Close([ref]$false)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to close the the file in your program. For me defer file.Close() (goLang) fixed it.